ActiveMQ Artemis web console (or Jolokia) for cluster info/management
When setting up an ActiveMQ Artemis broker cluster (e.g. by deploying ArtemisCloud in a K8s environment) is there a way to expose the web console or Jolokia that get information about the cluster (total connections/sessions, total addresses, ...)?
The following configuration for an ArtemisCloud deployment exposes (via service and ingress) the web console for only the first instance (pod) and with minimal info about the cluster:
apiVersion: broker.amq.io/v1beta1
kind: ActiveMQArtemis
metadata:
  name: artemis-broker
spec:
  console:
    expose: true
...
  deploymentPlan:
    size: 2


The configuration for an ArtemisCloud deployment exposes (via service and ingress) the web console and the jolokia API for all the broker instances (pods), i.e. if your ingress domain is my-domain.com the operator will create a service and an ingress for every broker instance:
apiVersion: broker.amq.io/v1beta1
kind: ActiveMQArtemis
metadata:
  name: artemis-broker
spec:
  console:
    expose: true
  deploymentPlan:
    size: 2
  ingressDomain: my-domain.com

$ kubectl get ingress
NAME                              CLASS   HOSTS                                                   ADDRESS        PORTS   AGE
artemis-broker-wconsj-0-svc-ing   nginx   artemis-broker-wconsj-0-svc-ing-default.my-domain.com   192.168.49.2   80      54s
artemis-broker-wconsj-1-svc-ing   nginx   artemis-broker-wconsj-1-svc-ing-default.my-domain.com   192.168.49.2   80      54s

You can use artemis-broker-wconsj-0-svc-ing-default.my-domain.com to access the console and the jolokia API of the broker 0 and artemis-broker-wconsj-1-svc-ing-default.my-domain.com to access the console and the jolokia API of the broker 1, i.e.
$ curl -u admin:admin 'http://artemis-broker-wconsj-0-svc-ing-default.my-domain.com:80/console/jolokia/read/org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker="amq-broker"/Status'
{"request":{"mbean":"org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker=\"amq-broker\"","attribute":"Status","type":"read"},"value":"{\"configuration\":{\"properties\":{\"broker.properties\":{\"alder32\":\"1\"},\"system-brokerconfig.\":{\"alder32\":\"1\"}}},\"server\":{\"jaas\":{\"properties\":{\"artemis-users.properties\":{\"reloadTime\":\"1718895679452\",\"Alder32\":\"2156146843\"},\"artemis-roles.properties\":{\"reloadTime\":\"1718895679452\",\"Alder32\":\"646579434\"}}},\"state\":\"STARTED\",\"version\":\"2.34.0\",\"nodeId\":\"e9b0a005-2f15-11ef-8f1c-d2555638396e\",\"identity\":null,\"uptime\":\"5 minutes\"}}","timestamp":1718896013,"status":200}

You can enable metrics and use Prometheus, to aggregate counters from multiple broker pods, i.e.
apiVersion: broker.amq.io/v1beta1
kind: ActiveMQArtemis
metadata:
  name: artemis-broker
spec:
  console:
    expose: true
  deploymentPlan:
    size: 2
    enableMetricsPlugin: true
  ingressDomain: my-domain.com


Ok, but there is no aggregate info about the cluster (but this is a problem about Artemis in general). Moreover ArtemisCloud ingress seems to conflict with another ingress configuration.

You can enable metrics and use Prometheus to aggregate counters from multiple broker instances. I updated my answer.
